# How do I use the "survival" package and Surv function in R with left-truncated data?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to run survival analysis using the `Surv` and `survfit` functions from the survival package.  Most of my data is left truncated, and I'm not sure if I'm entering it into the `Surv` function right.  My response variable is time (measured in years) beginning from when a bridge is classified as deficient, and ending when it collapses.  I can track each bridge's deficiency status from 2012 back to 1992, but no further.  The censoring occurs because many bridges were classified as deficient from the time of their collapse back to 1992, and thus I don't know exactly when they became deficient, and therefore I don't know their true "lifetime" (number of years from deficient classification to collapse).  Say for example a 
bridge collapsed in 1995, and was classified as being deficient in 1995, 1994, 1993, and 1992.  It is possible that it was first classified as being deficient in 1992, it is 
also possible that it has been classified as deficient since 1984.  Thus I believe my censoring is considered to be left truncated.

Some example data:

```
Year0 = c(1992, 1992, 1999, 1992, 1993, 2007, 2005, 1992) # The years when each bridge     was first observed as being deficient.
Year1 = c(1993, 1994, 2002, 1996, 2004, 2012, 2011, 2000) # The years in which each bridge collapsed
Defyears = Year1 - Year0 + 1 # The number of years for wich I can observe each bridge being deficient
time1 = Year0 - 1992 # Since I want the time scale to be from 0 to 21 instead of 1992 - 2012, I subtract 1992 from each time observation.
                     # This now becomes the beginning point for the lifetime of each bridge.
time2 = Defyears + time1 # This is the ending point of the lifetime of each bridge.
n = length(time2)
```

Notice that four out of the eight bridges are left truncated, bridge 1, 2, 4, and 8.  I 
cannot observe exactly when they were first classified as being deficient.  For bridges
3, 5, 6, and 7 I know their exact lifetimes since they became deficient after 1992, hence
these observations are not censored.

I then fit the below model:

```
bridges = survfit(Surv(time = time1, time2 = time2, event = rep(1,n)) ~ 1) # I do "event = rep(1,n)" because each bridge collapsed.
```

I'm just not sure that this model is correct.  For one thing, in the documentation it 
says that "time" is for right censored data or the starting time for interval censored data. For another, I don't see how this model accounts for the observations that aren't censored.  Can anyone tell me if this is right, and if not, what I need to change and why.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: What's needed here is the data on the bridges that didn't collapse.

Answer (score 2):

See if these make better sense:

```
> clps <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0) #censor flag
> surv.obj <- Surv(rep(0, length(clps)), Year1-Year0+1, clps)
> surv.obj #Is this what you want?
[1] (0, 2+] (0, 3+] (0, 4 ] (0, 5+] (0,12 ] (0, 6 ] (0, 7 ] (0, 9+]
> survRzt <- survfit(surv.obj~1)
> plot(survRzt)
```

[image]

My understanding is that you are trying to analyze the duration between being classified as deficient to the eventual failure. For a 'left truncated' (see more of that in my reply) data, say the 1st bridge, even it only spend 2 year in that duration, it in fact may have stayed for more than 2 year (`2+`) as you aren't  able to back date prior to 1992. To make that reflected in the `surv` object, instead of putting a `1` flag to it, I put a `0`.

For the other data points, such as the 3rd bridge. The length of duration is 4 years and we known it is exactly 4 years. It should get a censor flag of `1`.

Comment: I've tried something like that before, but isn't that right censoring?  My concern with using a censor flag like the one you described is that it implies the event hasn't happened for those bridges with censor flag == 0.  But that's not the case, all bridges in the data set have collapsed.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: That will be a question more suitable for crossvalidated instead of stackoverflow. But I don't think it is really left truncated. Left truncated means if lifetime is less than a threshold that event is not observed. In your case, lifetime is the amount of time between being tagged as defunct and collapse. Left truncation doesn't apply to it. And yes, I think, counter intuitively, these are right-censored observations.

Comment: Note that we are providing both `time1` and `time2`, it is treated as an interval-censored dataset. Status indicator, normally means `0=alive, 1=dead`, means `0=right censored, 1=event at time` now.

Comment: Alright thanks I'm going to keep thinking about it, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's really not right censored data either. The data gathering has eliminated the "surviving bridges, so there's no reference set of covariates with which to make any sort of risk estimate.